# Centos 5.5 Installation - Configuring Root Partition

Tags: linux, installation, partitioning, centos

I installed the Centos 5.5 on a WM instance. Run out of space after doing the updates. It is very difficult to keep re-partitioning /

I tried to install a new instance but it doesn't let me configure the disc and it just goes and install the OS.

How can I use the good old installation options etc?

What happened to control? This became a control nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this site
http://alstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-centos-step-by-step.html

the main step being that you check the option : "I will install the operating system later"

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your exact environment, but you should install the OS using a kickstart file, ks.cfg. You can make one from scratch or use the one created by a previous successful installation, which you make accessible over the net or on boot media.

If you look in the /root directory of the last good installation that you did, you should find a file called anaconda-ks.cfg - this can be used or modified as the basis for the next installation.
Here is an example of one I did for Centos 5.1 a few years ago:

```
# Kickstart file automatically generated by anaconda.

install
url --url http://192.168.41.2/mrepo/centos5-x86_64/disc1
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard uk
network --device eth0 --bootproto dhcp
network --device eth1 --bootproto dhcp
rootpw --iscrypted $1$AI501gDE$T4FnEOs9RvFgj4scrhvwV.
firewall --enabled --port=22:tcp
authconfig --enableshadow --enablemd5
selinux --enforcing
timezone --utc Europe/London
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda
# The following is the partition information you requested
# Note that any partitions you deleted are not expressed
# here so unless you clear all partitions first, this is
# not guaranteed to work
#clearpart --linux --drives=sda
#part /boot --fstype ext3 --size=100 --ondisk=sda
#part pv.4 --size=0 --grow --ondisk=sda
#volgroup VolGroup00 --pesize=32768 pv.4
#logvol swap --fstype swap --name=LogVol01 --vgname=VolGroup00 --size=1000 --grow --maxsize=1984
#logvol / --fstype ext3 --name=LogVol00 --vgname=VolGroup00 --size=1024 --grow

%packages
@base
@core
@dialup
@editors
@text-internet
```

Uncommenting the partition info above should allow them to be created on a new blank system.